# select two values in one option html form php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

how i can select two values in one form select html?

how explode exactly?

```
this is my table
id   name      divition
1    john      IT
2    blair     ACCOUNTING
3    Fira      Finance
```

i have form like this

```
<select name="select" id="divi">
    <option value="it">IT</option>
    <option value="ACCOUNTING.FINANCE">Accounting Finance</option>
```

and the php process will be like this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$divi = $_POST['divi'];
$divi = explode(".",$divi);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE divition = '$divi'";
```

i need show data when user select Acc & Finance it will show all name with divition Accounting and finance.

Thank you so much

Comment: Split the value on the ".", then build the where clause using like .. and...

Comment: how to do that?
can u show me the code?
im frustated to google that

Comment: For the accounting/finance, your where clause should look something like: ```WHERE divition like 'ACCOUNTING' OR divition like 'FINANCE'```

Comment: You cant, place an array in a string. $divi is an array now.

Comment: how to do that with variable?
because my code like that one not just one

Comment: You've tried my post?...

Comment: Any reactions? :)

Answer (score 0):

An option is to loop through the array `$divi`

like:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $divi = $_POST['divi'];
  $divi = explode(".",$divi);

  $sql = "";
  foreach($divi as $field) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE divition = '$field'";
  }
```

Comment: Is an optional way indeed ;)

Comment: Okay, show me a bit more code, so I know what you are doing.

Comment: DO NOT use this SQL -- it is insecure.  A single prepared statement should be used.

Answer (score 0):

How can you do that -

Accounting & Finance are in different row.
Instead of that use multiple select option Tag values.

Comment: how can you bind data in 2nd option Tag like (Acounting Finance)